# Which API to call in WebSphere (Liberty) for root cause of failure of login using custom user registry?

Tags: java, authentication, websphere, websphere-liberty, user-registry

**WebSphere (traditional)**: In case of container based authentication with `custom user registry`, when the login from web application failed, we used to find
the root cause of failure by calling:

`com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.getRootLoginException();`

The above API exists in: {Server_Root_Dir}/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime_x.y.z.jar

The decompiled source-code of the method `getRootLoginException()` is:

```
public static Throwable getRootLoginException(){
   return ContextManagerFactory.getInstance().getRootException();
}
```

**WebSphere (Liberty)**: In case of container based authentication with `custom user registry`, we are not able to find
the root cause of failure of login by calling:

`com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.getRootLoginException();`

The above API exists in: {Server_Root_Dir}/lib/com.ibm.websphere.security_x.y.z.jar

It is because the decompiled source-code of the method `getRootLoginException()` is:

```
public static Throwable getRootLoginException(){
   return null;
}
```

But in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/security/auth/WSSubject.html

IBM claims that:

> **public static java.lang.Throwable getRootLoginException()**
>
> This convenient method returns the root login exception caught in the
>   system login module, if one exists.
>
> It will extract the exception from the current thread. You will get
>   what the login module sees as the root exception. This could be a
>   nested exception. You may need to extract exceptions from the
>   exception returned until you get the real root exception.
>
> Returns:
>       A Throwable containing the root login exception. If a login exception did not occur, null will be returned.

I would like to know which API to call in WebSphere (Liberty) in order to find the root cause of failure of login.

**Why WSSubject.getRootLoginException() is needed:**

The custom implementation of `com.ibm.websphere.security.UserRegistry` requires that you validate the username and password entered by the web application user by providing your own definition of `checkPassword(String userSecurityName, String passwd)`. Please see http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/csec_customauth.html

If the user provides incorrect information you may throw `PasswordCheckFailedException` or `CustomRegistryException` with your message. This `checkPassword(String userSecurityName, String passwd)` is  actually invoked by the WebSphere (traditional or Liberty) from JAAS `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule.login()` and `PasswordCheckFailedException` or `CustomRegistryException` and their  messages are wrapped and `javax.security.auth.login.LoginException` is thrown.

In order to provide feedback to the web application user we need to get hold of the Exception thrown from `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule.login()`.
The way to do this is by calling `com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSSubject.getRootLoginException()` from a servlet filter. This works fine in WebSphere (traditional) but not any more  in WebSphere (Liberty). The problem is that IBM has not documented this limitation anywhere.

Comment: what do you want to know from the root exception ?

Comment: Please see the section `Why WSSubject.getRootLoginException() is needed`.

Answer (score -1):

In traditional WAS this was resolved as APAR [PM21010](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM21010) a long time ago. You might want to file a PMR, especially since [Brian found](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=71791050-5ad9-45be-b932-31b7fef5ce96) that this is documented as a supported API in WebSphere Liberty Profile.